# Cant make my wordpress url_rewrite work

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am working on a simple wordpress plugin to manage events.
I have a link in my layout where I want to link to a event-page which is located in my plugin folder.

I dont want the long url like `localhost/project/wp-content/plugins/event-manager/event-page.php?eventid=1`.

I want it to be like `localhost/project/event/1`. Where the `1` is referred to the eventid get.

I've searched a lot and still I cant find the way to get it worked.

My code is as follow:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'link_rewrite');

function link_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^event/^[0-9]', plugins_url('event-manager') . '/event-page.php?       eventid=$matches[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'link_rewrite_query_vars');

function link_rewrite_query_vars($query_vars) {
     $query_vars[] = 'eventid';
     return $query_vars;
}
```

Hope someone have a solution.